# Discord.py | How to get who is getting interaction with message

Tags: python, discord.py

Discord.py version: v2.1.0

Hello how can i get who is trying to interacted with message?

I just only found interaction.user but that only gaves me author

I researched in forums and documention but got nothing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you don't want the `author` then who do you want? The author _will_ be who triggered the command/interaction.

Comment: I want to prevent others from using it so only author can interacted with select menu

Comment: Can you provide your code for how the view/select menu is created? and the code for the view itself? I have an answer for you but having your code context would help.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have understood you but if you want to check if the user/member that sent the interaction is the bot's owner you can try `interaction.client.owner_id == interaction.user.id`

Comment: I found a way to do it: Just store the ctx.author.id in \_\_init__ but the variable will be overwritten if someone is used command